Zombie book identification request
I read a book, part of a series I think, in an apocalyptic setting. There are zombies, and killing certain zombies gave the humans certain abilities—like travelling through the earth, making dead cars run—that sort of thing. Does anybody know what this was?

Welcome: To help find the answer, please supply more details. When you read the book, more information about characters and the plot - thank you!

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

The Onset? People get skills from killing zombies, and it is a series, but I don't think there is a "starting dead cars" or "travel through the earth" skill.

That's not it but thankyou!. I distinctly remember one chap could travel like a mole underground,  I think another got very strong, but each time they killed, they risked burning up and dieing!
